# Adding tooltips to candlestick using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, candlestick-chart

I am using d3.js for a zoomable candlestick chart.It's working fine but I need to write a tool tip for showing OHLC values. I did some reference to try, but I failed. Can somebody help me to debug? Thank you very much!

Here is my code and it is very long, but for tooltips part, it's in the middle part.

```
function drawChart() {

    d3.csv("amazon.csv").then(function(prices) {

        const months = {0 : 'Jan', 1 : 'Feb', 2 : 'Mar', 3 : 'Apr', 4 : 'May', 5 : 'Jun', 6 : 'Jul', 7 : 'Aug', 8 : 'Sep', 9 : 'Oct', 10 : 'Nov', 11 : 'Dec'}

        var dateFormat = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
        for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {

            prices[i]['Date'] = dateFormat(prices[i]['Date'])
        }

        const margin = {top: 15, right: 65, bottom: 205, left: 50},
            w = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
            h = 625 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("#container")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" +margin.left+ "," +margin.top+ ")");

        let dates = _.map(prices, 'Date');

        var xmin = d3.min(prices.map(r => r.Date.getTime()));
        var xmax = d3.max(prices.map(r => r.Date.getTime()));
        var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-1, dates.length])
            .range([0, w])
        var xDateScale = d3.scaleQuantize().domain([0, dates.length]).range(dates)
        let xBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(d3.range(-1, dates.length)).range([0, w]).padding(0.3)
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
            .scale(xScale)
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                d = dates[d]
                // hours = d.getHours()
                // minutes = (d.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + d.getMinutes()
                // amPM = hours < 13 ? 'am' : 'pm'
                // return hours + ':' + minutes + amPM + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear()
                return d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear()
            });

        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("id","rect")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("pointer-events", "all")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

        var gX = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis x-axis") //Assign "axis" class
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
            .call(xAxis)

        gX.selectAll(".tick text")
            .call(wrap, xBand.bandwidth())

        var ymin = d3.min(prices.map(r => r.Low));
        var ymax = d3.max(prices.map(r => r.High));
        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([ymin, ymax]).range([h, 0]).nice();
        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
            .scale(yScale)

        var gY = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis y-axis")
            .call(yAxis);

        var chartBody = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "chartBody")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

        // draw rectangles
        let candles = chartBody.selectAll(".candle")
            .data(prices)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i) - xBand.bandwidth())
            .attr("class", "candle")
            .attr('y', d => yScale(Math.max(d.Open, d.Close)))
            .attr('width', xBand.bandwidth())
            .attr('height', d => (d.Open === d.Close) ? 1 : yScale(Math.min(d.Open, d.Close))-yScale(Math.max(d.Open, d.Close)))
            .attr("fill", d => (d.Open === d.Close) ? "silver" : (d.Open > d.Close) ? "red" : "green")

        // draw high and low
        let stems = chartBody.selectAll("g.line")
            .data(prices)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .attr("class", "stem")
            .attr("x1", (d, i) => xScale(i) - xBand.bandwidth()/2)
            .attr("x2", (d, i) => xScale(i) - xBand.bandwidth()/2)
            .attr("y1", d => yScale(d.High))
            .attr("y2", d => yScale(d.Low))
            .attr("stroke", d => (d.Open === d.Close) ? "white" : (d.Open > d.Close) ? "red" : "green");

        // -1- Create a tooltip div that is hidden by default:
        let tooltip = d3.select("#container")
            .append("div")
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("background-color", "black")
            .style("border-radius", "5px")
            .style("padding", "10px")
            .style("color", "white");

        // -2- Create 3 functions to show / update (when mouse move but stay on same circle) / hide the tooltip
        let showTooltip = function(d) {
            tooltip
              .transition()
              .duration(200);
            tooltip
              .style("opacity", 1)
                .html("Open: " + d.Open)
                .html("High: " + d.High)
                .html("Low: " + d.Low)
                .html("Close: " + d.Close)
              .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+30) + "px")
              .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]+30) + "px")
        };
        let moveTooltip = function() {
            tooltip
              .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+30) + "px")
              .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]+30) + "px")
        };
        let hideTooltip = function() {
              tooltip
                  .transition()
                  .duration(200)
                  .style("opacity", 0)
        };

        svg.append("defs")
            .append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .on("mouseover", showTooltip )// -3- Trigger the functions
            .on("mousemove", moveTooltip )
            .on("mouseleave", hideTooltip);

        const extent = [[0, 0], [w, h]];

        var resizeTimer;
        var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 100])
            .translateExtent(extent)
            .extent(extent)
            .on("zoom", zoomed)
            .on('zoom.end', zoomend);

        svg.call(zoom);

        function zoomed() {

            var t = d3.event.transform;
            let xScaleZ = t.rescaleX(xScale);

            let hideTicksWithoutLabel = function() {
                d3.selectAll('.xAxis .tick text').each(function(d){
                    if(this.innerHTML === '') {
                        this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'
                    }
                })
            };

            gX.call(
                d3.axisBottom(xScaleZ).tickFormat((d, e, target) => {
                    if (d >= 0 && d <= dates.length-1) {
                        d = dates[d];
                        // hours = d.getHours()
                        // minutes = (d.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + d.getMinutes()
                        // amPM = hours < 13 ? 'am' : 'pm'
                        // return hours + ':' + minutes + amPM + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear()
                        return d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear()
                    }
                })
            );

            candles.attr("x", (d, i) => xScaleZ(i) - (xBand.bandwidth()*t.k)/2)
                .attr("width", xBand.bandwidth()*t.k);
            stems.attr("x1", (d, i) => xScaleZ(i) - xBand.bandwidth()/2 + xBand.bandwidth()*0.5);
            stems.attr("x2", (d, i) => xScaleZ(i) - xBand.bandwidth()/2 + xBand.bandwidth()*0.5);

            hideTicksWithoutLabel();

            gX.selectAll(".tick text")
                .call(wrap, xBand.bandwidth())

        }

        function zoomend() {
            var t = d3.event.transform;
            let xScaleZ = t.rescaleX(xScale);
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {

                var xmin = new Date(xDateScale(Math.floor(xScaleZ.domain()[0])));
                xmax = new Date(xDateScale(Math.floor(xScaleZ.domain()[1])));
                filtered = _.filter(prices, d => ((d.Date >= xmin) && (d.Date <= xmax)));
                minP = +d3.min(filtered, d => d.Low);
                maxP = +d3.max(filtered, d => d.High);
                buffer = Math.floor((maxP - minP) * 0.1);

                yScale.domain([minP - buffer, maxP + buffer]);
                candles.transition()
                    .duration(800)
                    .attr("y", (d) => yScale(Math.max(d.Open, d.Close)))
                    .attr("height",  d => (d.Open === d.Close) ? 1 : yScale(Math.min(d.Open, d.Close))-yScale(Math.max(d.Open, d.Close)));

                stems.transition().duration(800)
                    .attr("y1", (d) => yScale(d.High))
                    .attr("y2", (d) => yScale(d.Low));

                gY.transition().duration(800).call(d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale));

            }, 500)

        }
    });
}

function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this),
            words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
            y = text.attr("y"),
            dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
            tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
            }
        }
    });
}

drawChart();
```

Comment: hi, could you make a functional example? You could use the snippet tool here

Comment: I second what @cal_br_mar mentioned above. Creating a functional example would help. Also provide some sample data as to what is in the amazon.csv file. This can be dummy data which just matches the structure of your original data.